# Replacing spaces in filename to pass to Clipboard with applescript

Tags: text, replace, applescript

I am working on a script to have Finder get a file's location locally, replace spaces with %20, then append localhost:// so the transformed file name can be inserted into email.

I've have used the replacing spaces code structure suggested elsewhere on stackoverflow but the code is coming up with error 1721. I am not sure what I've done wrong.

The code for text substitution is:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set newString to {"localhost://"}
    set aString to "/file name input/"
    set aString to aString as text
    set charToReplace to " "
    set newChar to "%20"
    repeat with i in aString
        if (i as string) is charToReplace then
            set end of newString to newChar
        else
            set end of newString to (i as string)
        end if
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

The output should be /file%20name%20input/

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure on that 1721 error, but here is an alternate method for string search and replacing.

It uses AppleScript's `text item delimiters`. I think of this technique akin to the split().join() method to replace text in JavaScript.

```
    set aString to "/file name input/"
    set my text item delimiters to " "
    set split_list to every text item of aString -- split in to list of everything between the spaces
    set my text item delimiters to "%20"
    set newString to (split_list as text) -- join, using the %20 as the delimter
    set newString to "localhost://" & newString -- prepend your protocol string
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a standard version of a search and replace sub-routine for Applescript:

```
set encodedString to searchAndReplace(aString, space, "%20")

on searchAndReplace(myString, oldText, newText)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldText
    set myList to text items of myString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to newText
    set myString to myList as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return myString
end searchAndReplace
```